# Выпадение согласных перед суффиксом -ну-

Tags: этимология

Чем вызвано выпадение согласных корня перед суффиксом -ну- в таких словах как:

**г**
тянуть
двинуть
брызнуть
тронуть

**д**
вянуть
грянуть
глянуть
стынуть
кинуть

**к**
прыснуть
плеснуть
блеснуть

**п**
льнуть
окунуть
кануть
 
тонуть

**т**
блеснуть

и т.п.?

Comment: Возможно, Вам будет интересна статья https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suffiks-66819.html

Answer (score 2):

УПРОЩЕНИЕ ГРУПП СОГЛАСНЫХ

В результате действия закона открытого слога в одном слоге не могли соединяться определенные сочетания согласных. Если такое соединение происходило, то наблюдалось упрощение групп согласных путем выпадения одного из согласных. Поэтому в современном русском языке наблюдаются чередования согласных с нулем звука в следующих случаях.

ДН → Н: увядать – увянуть; взгляд – взглянуть. Вместо ожидаемых увяднуть (из увяд + нуть), взгляднуть (из взгляд + нуть) в результате упрощения дн в н имеем современные формы увянуть, взглянуть.

ТН → Н: свертывать – свернуть. Вместо ожидаемого свертнуть (из сверт + нуть) в результате упрощения тн в н имеем современную форму свернуть.

ГН → Н: трогать – тронуть; тяга - тянуть. Вместо ожидаемых трогнуть (из трог + нуть), тягнуть (из тяг + нуть) в результате упрощения гн в н имеем современные формы тронуть, тянуть.

КН → Н: плеск – плеснуть; треск – треснуть. Вместо ожидаемых плескнуть (из плеск + нуть), трескнуть (из треск + нуть) в результате упрощения кн в н имеем современные формы плеснуть, треснуть.

БН → Н: сгибать – согнуть. Вместо ожидаемого согбнуть (из согб + нуть) в результате упрощения бн в н имеем современную форму согнуть.

ПН → Н: спать – сны, липнуть - льнуть. Вместо ожидаемых снпать (из сн + пать), льпнуть (из льп + нуть) в результате упрощения пн в нимеем современные формы спать, льнуть. http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-100357.html?page=8