# Пядь и распнуть

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова пядь и распять к этимологически однокоренным исходя из следующего:

1. выпадение в русском согласной корня "д" перед глагольным окончанием -ть

Например, да**д**им, но да**ть**

2. выпадение в русском согласной корня "д" перед суффиксом -ну (см. [увя**д**ать -> вя**ну**ть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448221/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83));
3. наличие в русском чередования согласных с/д (см. [я**д**ь -> я**с**ти](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5));
4. наличие в русском чередования я/е (**я**дро -> н**е**дра, **я**дь -> сн**е**дь )

То есть:

1. пя**д**ь -> *рас*пя**ть**
2. пя**д**ь -> *рас*п**ну**ть
3. пя**д**ь -> пе**с**ти
4. п**я**дь -> п**е**сти

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос в том, являются ли они однокоренными или можно ли прийти к такому выводу, исходя из приведённых Вами доводов? Если первое, то да, этимологи, среди которых Преображенский, Фасмер, Черных, прямо об этом говорят. Приведу выдержку из словаря Цыганенко:

> > **ПЯДЬ** «мера длины, равная расстоянию между концами растянутых большого и указательного пальцев», «незначительная часть пространства». Древнее славянское слово. Современная его форма развилась из праславянского *рędь «пядь» вследствие изменения носового ę > 'a (графич. *я*). Праславянское *рędь образовано с пом. утрач. предметного суф. -d-ь от глаг. *рęti, *рьнQ, давшего др.-рус. *пѧти*, *пьну* «растягивать, распинать». Следовательно, пядь — это «мера длины по распяленной руке» > «незначительное 
> >     пространство» (*пядь земли*). См. запятая, пинать, путы, пяльцы.