# Значение слова "гряный"

Tags: этимология

Подскажите значение слова "Гряный".  В контексте "Гряная неделя" — одно из названий праздника Зелёные Святки.

Comment: Может связано с выпадением "д" перед "н" от глагола [грядёт](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448221/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83)

Answer (score 3):

Семицкая неделя бывает на седьмой неделе после Пасхи и получила такое народное название от Сем**и**ка. Эта неделя в старину известна была под именем Русальной. Малорусы называют её зелёною, клечальною, а последние три дня зелёными святками. Около Стародуба её величают Греною, где и семицкие песни называются Гренухами.

Т. е. слова "гряный" сейчас нет. Есть "гренухи" - некие песни обрядовые и есть "греная неделя", которая так называется потому, что тогда как раз поют гренухи. 
ГрЕная/грЯная — это обычное чередование гласных.

А вот в старославянском "гр(я|е)ный" означало "зеленый" (ср. англ. green).

Comment: Хороший ответ, поддержу, только по поводу *в старославянском "гр(я|е)ный" означало "зеленый"* просьба уточнить, откуда информация. Трубачёв в своём словаре отмечает, что в украинском оно имеет значение "зелёный", но ничего такого нет глубже в этимологической цепочке. Там всё от индо-европейского "расти" через праславянское "ветка, гроздь и т.п.".

Comment: Всю цепочку проследить, увы, тоже не смогу. Натыкался в нескольких источниках просто как на констатацию факта. Вот, например https://goo.gl/t85hJg

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая ссылка. Но всё же мой вопрос был про старославянский, а там ничего такого нет, только про украинский (как и у Трубачёва, который как раз на Гринченко и ссылается). Если не уверены по поводу старославянского, было бы хорошо заменить его в ответе на "в украинском". Ну или пусть так остаётся с нашими комментариями.

Comment: https://goo.gl/qfth5w Иваницкий говорит именно о старославянском. Но я не знаю, кто это и можно ли его считать авторитетом.  UPD: С другой стороны в современном украинском я не встречал это слово никогда, да и у классиков не припоминаю. Я думаю, что говорить о равенстве понятий "гряный"="зеленый" в украинском некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо! Это здорово, что Вы нашли источник. Сам по себе источник достаточно авторитетен [для нашего уровня обсуждения как минимум], хотя никто не застрахован от неточностей/ошибок. Я тоже не встречал в украинском (впрочем, неудивительно — я на украинском сейчас читаю не так уж много и даже не догадался на нём погуглить).